# Prevent pages from rendering if the user is not logged in

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm using Lazy loading to render pages in my application.

```
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

Problem is if I type www.mydomain.com/dashboard in the URL, the browser actually renders the dashboard page even though the user is not logged in and the redirect to the login screen after a second or two.

How do I prevent the browser from rendering any page at all if the user is not logged in? Basically it should straightaway redirect to the login page.

**AuthGuard Class**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  result: boolean = false;
  auth: any;
  outRes: any;


  constructor(private _authService: JwtService, private _router: Router) {

  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    this.outRes = this._authService.isAuthenticated();

    if (this.outRes) {
      this.outRes.subscribe(o => o ? true : this._authService.redirectToLogin());

      return true; 
    } else {

      this._authService.redirectToLogin();
      return false;
    }

  }

}
```

**Service Class**

```
  public isAuthenticated() {

    if (!this.loggedIn)
      this.redirectToLogin();

    return this.httpClient.get<boolean>(`${this.settings.getApiSettings('uri')}/api/auth/IsTokenValid`, {
      params: { token: this.getToken }
    }).map( /// <<<=== use `map` here
      (response) => {

        if (response !== null) {

          var receivedToken = response["securityStamp"];
          var availableToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

           //Check if received a refreshed token. (tokens are refreshed every 15 minutes)
          if (receivedToken && receivedToken !== availableToken) {

            localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response["securityStamp"]);

          }

        }

        let data = response;
        if (data == null)
          return false;
        else
          return true;

      }
    );

  }

  redirectToLogin() {

    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    window.location.href = "./login";

  }
```

Comment: did you write `canActivate` in your router?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is this `if (this.outRes)` and this `o => o ? true : this._authService.redirectToLogin()` , you always get `true` because your function will always return a response and it will never be null;
you're basically checking if there is response but not what type of response (true/false);

```
 canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    let isAuth: any;
    this._authService.isAuthenticated()
       .subscribe(response => isAuth = response); //<== this can true or false based on service

    if (!isAuth) {
      this._authService.redirectToLogin();
    }
     return isAuth;
  }
```